# Why is there a trailing none when reading text in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a text reader program that can differ a text into three parts: title, tag, and content.

what happen is that it's giving me a 'None' value at each end of the content.

here is the content reader code:

```
#counting lines in the text
def bufcount(file):
    file.seek(0)
    lines = 0
    buf_size = 1024 * 1024
    read_f = file.read # loop optimization

    buf = read_f(buf_size)
    while buf:
        lines += buf.count('\n')
        buf = read_f(buf_size)
    return lines

#for reading the content
def searchForTheContent(file):
    count=bufcount(file)
    file.seek(0)
    i=3 #to read after the third line, which is the content
    lines=file.readlines()
    while i<count:
        i=i+1
        #print(i)
        if lines[i]=="\n":
            pass
        if lines[i]!="\n":
            print(lines[i])
```

Calling the Function:

```
path= '.\\Texts\\*.txt'
files = glob.glob(path)

for name in files:
    file= open(name)
    print(searchForTheContent(file))
```

Result:

```
safahsdfhajfha
dfasdfsdfsadf

sadfasdfasdfasdfasdf

asdfasfdasd
None
```

Where is that 'None' value come from? and any suggestion how to remove it?

Comment: That `None` is *not* coming from the code you've shown here. How do you *call* the `searchForTheContent()` function? Did you perhaps use `print(searchForTheContent(filename))`?

Comment: it was like this:

print(searchForTheContent(file))

Comment: Well, since `searchForTheContent()` returns `None`, you are printing *that return value*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters i'm sorry for more question coming up with this, since i'm very new to the python and the stackoverflow as well. 

to my understanding, what you said is that the code might print beyond the content. but, i think the function that counted the line should have limited the reading loop?

Comment: This has nothing to do with your loop or reading from a file. You get the same result with `def foo(): pass`, and then `print(foo())`. You are printing the return value of a function, and here that function returns `None`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are printing the return value for the function:

```
print(searchForTheContent(file))
```

`searchForTheContent()` has no explicit `return` statement, so `None` is returned, and you are printing that. You'd get the same result with an empty function:

```
>>> def foo(): pass
...
>>> print(foo())
None
```

Remove that `print()` call:

```
for name in files:
    file= open(name)
    searchForTheContent(file)
```

Just to be explicit: `print()` doesn't 'return' anything to the caller; `print()` sends output to the `stdout` stream, which usually is connected to your terminal which is why you see the output there. That output is not also given as a return value.